# Websockets on tomcat 7 does not work

Tags: java, websocket, java-8, tomcat7

I try run websocket client under tomcat 7 using java 8, but it throw exception

```html
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/inter] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.websocket.ContainerProvider: Provider org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsContainerProvider not a subtype] with root cause
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.websocket.ContainerProvider: Provider org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsContainerProvider not a subtype
 at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
 at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
 at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
 at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
 at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
 at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:66)
 at com.shop.inter.service.WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:29)
```

...

It works on tomcat 8 but does not work on tomcat 7.
It is my websocket class:

```html
@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketClientEndpoint.class);
 
 private Session userSession = null;
 private MessageHandler messageHandler;

 public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
  try {
   WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
   container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }

 /**
  * Callback hook for Connection open events.
  * 
  * @param userSession
  *            the userSession which is opened.
  */
 @OnOpen
 public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
  LOGGER.info("opening websocket");
  this.userSession = userSession;
 }

 /**
  * Callback hook for Connection close events.
  * 
  * @param userSession
  *            the userSession which is getting closed.
  * @param reason
  *            the reason for connection close
  */
 @OnClose
 public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
  LOGGER.info("closing websocket");
  this.userSession = null;
 }

 /**
  * Callback hook for Message Events. This method will be invoked when a client send a message.
  * 
  * @param message
  *            The text message
  */
 @OnMessage
 public void onMessage(String message) {
  if (this.messageHandler != null) {
   this.messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
  }
 }

 /**
  * Register message handler
  */
 public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
  this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
 }

 /**
  * Send a message.
  */
 public void sendMessage(String message) {
  this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
 }

 public void closeUserSession() throws IOException {
  this.userSession.close();
 }

 /**
  * Message handler.
  * 
  * @author Jiji_Sasidharan
  */
 public static interface MessageHandler {

  public void handleMessage(String message);
 }
}
```

The only dependency is javax.websocket-api 1.1

Could you please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495227/web-socket-client-not-working-in-tomcat), try adding javaee-api to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```